# heroku postgis makemigrations error geodjango

Tags: python, django, heroku, geodjango, buildpack

So I have multi build pack installed for my build pack for heroku

```
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

and I have the .buildpacks file

```
https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git#1.3
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
```

The installation works but when I run python manage.py makemigrations I get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine PostGIS version 
for database "d34ce1ddsg9nkp". GeoDjango requires at least PostGIS version 1.3. 
Was the database created from a spatial database template?
```

I have tried multiple ways of setting the database in settings.py such as:

```
        GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = environ.get('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
        GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = environ.get('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
and
        GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = "{}/libgeos_c.so".format(environ.get('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH'))
        GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = "{}/libgdal.so".format(environ.get('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I fixed this by enabling postgis on heroku by running these commands

```
heroku pg:psql
create extension postgis;
```

then I ran this command to see what version i had on heroku

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

then I put this is my settings.py file

```
POSTGIS_VERSION = (2, 1, 5)
```

and viola it works!

Comment: Best answer ever! Thanks!!